# Pass the notebook output as paramater to copy activity

Tags: azure, parameters, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

I have the simple query in dabricks notebook that gives me an output which Im willing to use a parameter inside the copy activity.

my notebook output strcture looks like thi:

```
"runOutput": {
    "values": [
        {
            "CHANGENR": "0209193944"
        }
    ]
},
```

Moreover, I also defined the parameters outside of the acitivities, such as incremental_rule and so on.
[image]

I would like to pass the notebook output  `0209193944` inside the copy activity, which should be concatoned with `incremental_rule` parameter.

[image]

tried this did not work.

`@{concat(pipeline().parameters.incremental_rule, activity('COPY_SAP_TABLE_CDPOS').output.runOutput.values,'''')}`

and the output is this

[image]

my desired output should look like this.

[image]

Comment: try `activity('COPY_SAP_TABLE_CDPOS').output.runOutput.values[0].CHANGENR'` in place of `activity('COPY_SAP_TABLE_CDPOS').output.runOutput.values`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Since you need to concatenate the value, you need to use property selection on the Databricks activity output to get the desired result. The following is a demonstration of the same:

[image]

- Replace the dynamic content `activity('COPY_SAP_TABLE_CDPOS').output.runOutput.values` with the following to achieve your requirement:

```
activity('COPY_SAP_TABLE_CDPOS').output.runOutput.values[0].CHANGENR
```

[image]

- Since you are already using String interpolation, there is no need for `concat`. So, I used something like below which gave the desired result with the value of `incremental_rule` parameter is `((OBJECTCLAS='BELEGR' and TABNAME='BSEGR') or (OBJECTCLAS = 'BELEG' and TABNAME='BSEG)) and CHANGENR>`:

```
@{pipeline().parameters.incremental_rule}'@{activity('COPY_SAP_TABLE_CDPOS').output.runOutput.values[0].CHANGENR}'
```

[image]